# Using CSS with Scrapy to extract all text without tags - failing

Tags: css, text, web-scraping, tags, scrapy

I see a lot of Xpath answers but no CSS ones. I have had success extracting all the text I require - but it's totally 'wrapped'? in tags, font details, etc. I am pulling a few of the role descriptions off [this](https://www.ikrut.com/application/RetrieveJob.aspx?cmp_uid=b756e5d0-6e96-481c-b6fc-60f0b140168a&job_id=52240&internalUrl=1) site.

The code I am using is adapted from the Scrapy tutorial - I want to extract all the job-related text off the site for each role:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('.mask-on-hover + a::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)

def parse_author(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):

        return response.css(query).extract()

    yield {
        'role': extract_with_css('h1::text'),
        'literature': extract_with_css('h3 span.info::text'),
        'date-posted': extract_with_css('h3 span#ctl00_spListed.info.listed::text'),
        'role-description': extract_with_css('#ctl00_regionContent_lblJobDescription span , strong::text'),}
```

My result for the particular page includes all the text, but also the html tags and elements including, span, style, font-size.

How do I get clean text in order of appearance on the site using CSS? Ideally I would like to keep the paragraph styles and deliver it to one cell in Excel/CSV ultimately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the css selectors are exactly what you want you could use the [remove_tags](http://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.html.remove_tags) method from w3lib, but I don't think it's necessary in your case, please try this:

```
'role-description': extract_with_css('#ctl00_regionContent_lblJobDescription span *::text')
```

Comment: The * worked ! Can you explain why? Only thing is there is no spacing between titles and paragraphs..

Comment: yes, it's like asking in xpath the `//text()` that means that any node internal to the span is asked for its text

Comment: Thanks - I tried to apply this to a different website, but identical coding structure and it's not working.. for [link](https://www.bdo.co.uk/en-gb/careers) using the code for the role description: ''role_description': extract_with_css('p span , #com\.peopleclick\.cp\.formdata\.JPM_ESSENTIALFUNCTIONS_label , #com\.peopleclick\.cp\.formdata\.JPM_DESCRIPTION_label *::text'),'

Comment: is this a valid css selector? btw the `*::text` should be at the end of every expression (the commas can be understood as `or` selectors), for example if you want all the text inside the `p span` selector it should be `p span *::text` if you want more selectors you should use something like `p span *::text, #id .class *::text, ...`